# SQLQuery - WHERE statement across two tables returns 0 results

Tags: mysql

Im running a query as per the below:-

```
unack_query = """
    SELECT aa.AlertObjectID,
    aa.TriggeredMessage,
    aa.Acknowledged,
    aa.AcknowledgedBy,
    aa.TriggeredDateTime,
    ao.EntityType,
    ao.EntityCaption,
    node.Caption,
    node.CustomProperties.DeviceOwner
    FROM Orion.AlertActive aa 
    INNER JOIN  Orion.AlertObjects ao
        ON aa.AlertObjectID = ao.AlertObjectID   
        LEFT JOIN Orion.Nodes node
            ON ao.RelatedNodeId = NodeID
    WHERE node.CustomProperties.DeviceOwner = 'Network Team' AND aa.Acknowledged = False
    ORDER BY aa.TriggeredDateTime DESC 
    """
```

This query returns zero results. However when I remove the "AND aa.Acknowledged = False" from the query it works. I can also see in the results that the Acknowledged field is a boolean. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this would fail?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking if `AND aa.Acknowledged = TRUE`  work  as when you have not the condition  ..(could be you have not false values)

or could be you have 'False' as  a string

```
 WHERE node.CustomProperties.DeviceOwner = 'Network Team' AND aa.Acknowledged = 'False'
```

or you could have no value so you should also check

```
WHERE node.CustomProperties.DeviceOwner = 'Network Team' AND aa.Acknowledged is null
```

Comment: you're right, I got is not set to anything if not True, this worked WHERE node.CustomProperties.DeviceOwner = 'Network Team' AND aa.Acknowledged IS Null